# Error installing PyQt5 + qtpy packages in in PyCharm 2020.1: SSL-module not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5, qtpy

After installing Qt (5.14.2) in Win10 I have created a new project in PyCharm 2020.1. From the project settings dialog, I have tried to install the PyQt5 and the qtpy packages. I get the following error:

```
Collecting PyQt5
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyqt5/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

SSL module is not available. How can I install it? Could you please help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273). .dll files have to be copied from the bin into the DLLs file.